# Object slicing and implicit type conversion

Tags: c++, type-conversion

Here's a simplified version of the code I'm using:

```
namespace BasketNovel {

void Engine::BuryEntities()
{
    std::list<Entity*>::iterator iter = p_entities.begin();
    while (iter != p_entities.end())
    {
        if ( (*iter)->getAlive() == false )
        {
            delete (*iter);
            iter = p_entities.erase( iter ); //.erase returns next element
        }
        else iter++;
    }
}
}
```

I'm getting the following warning from Intel Static Analysis:

> BasketNovel.cpp(567): warning #12221: slicing of object "iter" passed as actual argument 2 in call to "std::_List_iterator > > std::list >::erase(std::_List_const_iterator > >)" occurs due to implicit type conversion

I believe that this is basically saying that I'm causing an implicit type conversion in:

iter = p_entities.erase( iter );

(note: I get the same warning even if I change my code to: p_entities.erase( iter++ ); )

I don't quite understand what I'm "slicing" in the above.
What exactly does this mean and how I should go about solving this warning? I'd rather slightly convoluted code than turning off warning messages completely.

Comment: how is `p_entities` declared?

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: @VaughnCato std::list<Entity*> p_entities;

Comment: Does it support C++11? Because the signature of `std::list::erase` changed.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes, as you've inferred. I've turned on C++11 support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is Object Slicing

*Object Slicing* is the fact of copying/moving only part of an object, this occurs in general with Base/Derived couples:

```
struct Base { int i; };

struct Derived: Base { int j; };

void slice() {
    Derived d = {};

    Base b(d); // b is a "sliced" version of `d`
}
```

and can lead to nastiness.

**Here** though, this is just a false positive...

> Can it be easier ?

Yes, certainly.

```
// Place to be deleted values at the end
auto const it = std::partition(p_entities.begin(), p_entities.end(),
                    [](Entity const* e) { return not e or not e->getAlive(); });

// Delete them
std::for_each(it, p_entities.end(), [](Entity const* e) { delete e; });

// Remove them
p_entities.erase(it, p_entities.end());
```

Comment: Great reply, really opened my eyes to C++11 usage. But I'm getting the same error with the final p_entities.erase. The compiler's telling me that I'm splitting 'it' and making an implicit type conversion. BTW, what do you mean by the false positive?

Comment: @dk123: *false positive* means the compiler is wrong in its analysis that this is a defect. It happens regularly with warnings: if the compiler was sure it would be an error, but because the analysis is not perfect it is only a warning that something might be awry..

Comment: Thanks for the definition. Is there any plausible way though that you think may perhaps circumvent the warning completely? (without just turning it off)

Comment: @dk123: maybe a `static_cast<const_iterator>(it)` to indicate it's intentional ? Unfortunately having never used icc I don't have better :(

Comment: Sadly, that didn't take care of the warning. I've accepted this as the answer though due to the clear definition of slicing and that great c++11 implementation. Thanks!

Comment: @dk123: I just realized that Intel may have cheated by making `iterator` inherit from `const_iterator` to get the automatic conversion for free and implement a lot of common functionality only once. This would explain the splicing warning :(

Comment: Ah, if so that splicing warning definitely makes sense :) Do you have any ideas how to take care of the warning then though? Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `std::list::erase()` method is expecting a `std::list<Entity*>::const_iterator` and you are passing it an `std::list<Entity*>::iterator`. This could mean you are compiling the code with C++11 support.

One solution would be to perform the removals in two steps. First, use `std::for_each` to delete and set to `0` pointers to objects that are not alive.

```
#include <algorithm>

void deleteDead(Entity* e) { 
  if (e->getAlive()) return; 
  delete e;
  e = 0;
}
std::for_each(p_entities.begin(), p_entities.end(), deleteDead);
```

Second, use the [erase-remove idiom]([erase-remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom) to remove elements that are `0`.

```
#include <algorithm>
p_entities.erase(std::remove(p_entities.begin(), p_entities.end(), 0), 
                 p_entities.end() );
```

Comment: I've just tried changing the statement to: iter = p_entities.erase( static_cast<std::list<Entity*>::const_iterator>(iter) ); but I'm still getting the same error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried the amendment but I'm getting the same error about erase: "std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<BasketNovel::Entity *,std::allocator<BasketNovel::Entity *> > > std::list<BasketNovel::Entity *,std::allocator<BasketNovel::Entity *> >::erase(std::_List_const_iterator<std::_List_val<BasketNovel::Entity *,std::allocator<BasketNovel::Entity *> > >,std::_List_const_iterator<std::_List_val<BasketNovel::Entity *,std::allocator<BasketNovel::Entity *> > >)" occurs due to implicit type conversion

Comment: **Don't!** The erase-remove idiom is only valid if you can safely **discard** the values. Here, the OP needs first to **delete** them.

Comment: @MatthieuM. thanks, I had missed the deletes. I provided an alternative solution, but I see it is quite similar to the one you posted.

Comment: @juanchopanza: we could argue that the OP ought to use `std::unique_ptr` and then the erase-remove idiom would apply cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

After about a month of doing other work, I've realised the answer to the problem was basically in changing

> std::list::iterator

to

> std::list::const_iterator

The slicing was occurring because .erase() required a const_iterator and made the implicit conversion from iterator.

I'd recommend typedef ing std::list in the header to cover possible future type changes.

I'm keeping MatthieuM.'s answer up though because I think the definition on Object Slicing is far more useful than this answer itself.